# Problem With Lower And Upper No-Arbitrage Barriers And Inequalities-Financial Mathematics

Tags: probability, inequality, stochastic-processes, martingales, finance

**EXERCISE**

> We consider a financial market of one period with two stocks $(S_0,S_1)$.
>   We further consider a purchase option with repayment $C = (S_1^{1} - K)^+$
>   with a value of $K> 0$ and maturing time $T = 1$. Let $\underline{π}(C)$,$\overline{π}(C)$ the lower and upper no-arbitrage barriers for the value of $C$.
>
> a)Show that the following inequality applies
>   $$\underline{π}(C)\geq \bigg(S_1^{1} - \dfrac{k}{1+r}\bigg)^+$$
>
> Please also show that the following equality applies
>   $$\underline{π}(C)= \bigg(S_1^{1} - \dfrac {k}{1+r}\bigg)^+$$
>
> if it is further assumed that:
>   $$P[S_1^{1}=S_0^{1} \cdot(1+r)]> 0$$
>
> **Hint :** Use the probability measure $$Q[·]: = P [·|S_1^{1} =S_0^{1}\cdot (1+r)]$$
>
> b) Also show that the following inequality applies
>   $$\underline {π}(C)\leq S_0^{1}$$
>
> and that the following equality applies
>   $$\overline{π}(C)=S_0^{1}$$
>
> assuming that $\rm ess \sup S_1^{1}=\infty $ and that $\rm ess \inf  S_1^{1}=0$.

**ATTEMPT**

a)We have a financial market with no-arbitrage so we have the form:
$$π(C)=E_Q\bigg[\dfrac{c}{1+r}\bigg]<\infty$$ for $Q\subset P$

So,$$\underline{π}(C)\geq \inf_{Q \in P}E_Q\bigg[\dfrac{c}{1+r}\bigg]=\inf_{Q \in P}E_Q\bigg[\dfrac{S_1^{1}-k}{1+r}\bigg]=\inf_{Q \in P}\dfrac{1} {1+r}E_Q[S_1^{1}-k]$$

**UPDATE**

Ι think that i have to use put-call-parity equation:

$$C_t-P_t=S_t-kB(t,T)$$
with $B(t,T)=\dfrac{S_0^{0}} {S_0^{1}}=\dfrac{1}{1+r}$

Then we rearrange the equation so that C is on the left hand side and use P_t>0 (using 1/(1+r) for the discount factor).So,we have $$C_t=P_t+S_t-k \dfrac{1}{1+r}$$

**Can anyone help me from here with a thorough solution so to find the question a)?**

**I don't know if this is right but i want to know if I am in the right way to solve the problem.**

Also,I would like to ask if $\min=\inf$ in this problem

For question b) i know that i have to take this theorem
[image]

and this remark but i don't know even how to start!
[image]

I would really appreciate any hints/thorough solution because it's the first problem that I have to solve and I don't have any experience in this type of exercise and generally it's my first try in the field of financial mathematics

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{(a)}$ From the extension of the Theorem hinted, the lower no-arbitrage bound is :
$$\underline{\pi}(C) = \inf_{\mathbb{Q} \in \mathcal{P}}\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}\bigg[\frac{C}{1+r}\bigg]=\inf_{\mathbb{Q} \in \mathcal{P}}\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}\bigg[\frac{(S_1^1 - K)^+}{1+r}\bigg]$$

The Jenses inequality in context of probability theory, says thati f $X$ is a random variable and $\varphi$ is a convex function, then it is :  $\varphi\big(\mathbb{E}[X]\big) \leq \mathbb{E}[\varphi(X)]$. The function $f(x) = (x-K)^+, \; K>0$ is convex, thus :

$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}\bigg[\frac{(S_1^1 - K)^+}{1+r}\bigg] \geq\frac{1}{1+r}\big[\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}(S_1^1 - K)\big]^+ $$
 $$= \frac{1}{1+r}\big[\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}(S_1^1) - \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}(K)\big]^+= \frac{1}{1+r}\bigg[S_0^1(1+r) - K\bigg]^+$$
$$\implies$$
$$\underline{\pi}(C) \geq \bigg(S_0^1 - \frac{K}{1+r}\bigg)^+$$
where the probability measure $\mathbb{Q}[\cdot] := \mathbb{P}[\cdot | S_1^1 = S_0^1(1+r)]$ was used.

Now if $\mathbb{P}[S_1^1 = S_0^1(1+r)] >0$, this means that at some point it will be $S_1^1 = S_0^1(1+r)$ and thus :

$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}\bigg[\frac{(S_1^1 - K)^+}{1+r}\bigg] = \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}\bigg[\frac{(S_0^1(1+r) - K)^+}{1+r}\bigg] = \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}\bigg[\bigg(S_0^1 - \frac{K}{1+r}\bigg)^+\bigg]$$
which means that the equality will hold, since $S_0^1$ is just a constant $>0$ :
$$\underline{\pi}(C) = \bigg(S_0^1 - \frac{K}{1+r}\bigg)^+$$

For part $\mathbf{(b)}$, again from the extension of the Theorem hinted, we have :
$$\overline{\pi}(C) = \sup_{\mathbb{Q} \in \mathcal{P}}\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}\bigg[\frac{C}{1+r}\bigg]=\sup_{\mathbb{Q} \in \mathcal{P}}\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}\bigg[\frac{(S_1^1 - K)^+}{1+r}\bigg]$$

But, note that simply it is :

$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}\bigg[\frac{(S_1^1 - K)^+}{1+r}\bigg] \leq \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}\bigg[\frac{S_1^1}{1+r}\bigg] = \frac{\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}(S_1^1)}{1+r} = S_0^1 $$
$$\implies$$
$$\overline{\pi}(C) \leq S_0^1 $$
where the probability measure $\mathbb{Q}[\cdot] := \mathbb{P}[\cdot | S_1^1 = S_0^1(1+r)]$ was used.

Can you figure out a similar approach for the last part now ?

Answer (score 2):

(a) Use put-call parity and the fact that the put price must be +ve. (b) Call price cannot exceed the value of the stock, as otherwise buying the stock and selling the call would generate an arbitrage profit.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?I understand that you tell to use the put-call parity equation which is $C_t-P_t=S_t-k \cdot B(t,T)$.What does "the put price must be +ve" means?

Comment: It means that the put price must be positive.

Comment: I can't see how to proceed with this information. Could you provide a thorough solution?

Comment: First, learn what the symbols mean. Then rearrange the equation so that $C$ is on the left hand side and use $P>0$ (using $1/(1+r)$ for the discount factor).

Comment: And after this?

Comment: Why use put call parity when you have the lower and upper no-arbitrage bounds ready by the theorem hinted in the exercise ? This answer complicates things.

Comment: As using put-call parity, coupled with the fact that option prices must be +ve, gives you the answer in one line, it's hard to see why this complicates things. The question is another example of dressing up a simple concept in fancy maths and calling it a theorem.

Comment: @RichardMartin Any idea about how to proof the equation assisted by $\rm ess \sup S_1^{1}=\infty $ and  $\rm ess \inf  S_1^{1}=0$ part??

Comment: In effect, you want to show that it's possible to push the call price arbitrarily close to the stock price, so that it is not possible to move the upper bound for the call lower than $S$. But again, this is obvious by put-call parity. We have $C\ge S-K/(1+r)$ and $K/(1+r)$ can be made arbitrarily small. So the upper bound cannot be $<S$.